# Display record detail of child record in parent record's aura lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, order, orderitem, aura-enabled

I am designing a custom lightning component to display a list of OrderItem records in a tabular format on parent Order record detail page. The requirement is to display the record detail page of an OrderItem below the table whenever an OrderItem is selected/clicked on. Is there a lightning aura component (similar to apex:detail in visualforce) that can do this job for me? If not, how can I build this in my lightning component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the lightning:recordForm component (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordForm/documentation). The component allows you to display the details of a particular record based on the Page Layout that you configured when the "Full" value for the **layoutType** parameter is used:

> Full - The full layout corresponds to the fields on the record detail
> page. From the management settings for the object that you want to
> edit, go to Page Layouts.

Comment: Instead of the record detail page if I want to display the entire record page with all the components example, related list tabs, custom components, etc in my custom lightning component, is it possible to do so?

Comment: Hi! I would say that it is not possible and, in that cause, probably makes more sense to just redirect to the view page of the record itself.